# Call or E-mail?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, email, phone

I recently got a phone call (they left a message) telling me a position had opened up and if I was still interested. Within a minute of that message, they also sent an e-mail simply restating the message, asking if I was interested.

I responded to the e-mail instead of calling back because:

1. I already had it pulled up.
2. I prefer communicating via e-mail for these things because it gives me a way to have a reference to what was said.

My question is, if given both a phone message and an e-mail, does it really matter which one is responded to? I don't really mean in terms of communicating, but in etiquette terms. Is there an unwritten rule about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you would respond back with whatever communication medium they initiate with. If they reach out using two methods, they've given you the opportunity to pick. I would say you made the right call by going with the email since it's your preferred method.

The only circumstance I could see being frowned upon would be if they only contacted you by phone, and you responded via email without the prompt. I think that would be poor etiquette, because the person contacting you had a preference and you ignored it. But when people use multiple methods to contact you, they're clearly comfortable with either.

Answer (score 2):

I would think about it like this: What if somebody else got the same call as you and responded via phone call? They automatically have spoken to the recruiter, and in my eyes, have one-up'd me. Usually what I do in situations such as this is I will send the email verifying that I'm still interested and if I have not heard anything by the next day I will generally call the recruiter and say "Hi, this is [Your Name], I got a call from [Whoever] about a potential job offer. I emailed them but I just wanted to verify the email was received and perhaps speak with [Whoever] about the job offer."

The reason I would do this is that many emails get buried. Quickly. Your email may not be seen by the recruiter for who knows how long.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen to me many times.  Get a call from a recruiter who leaves a message and also sends me an email with the job information.

9 times out of 10 when I actually talk to recruiters I have them send me the email with the job description any way so they saved me a step.

After talking to the recruiter or receiving an email I will review the position.  If after reviewing the position I find I have no interest, I will normally shoot them an email back thanking them for their time and why the position would not be a fit (This accomplishes 2 things says yes I am alive and this is what would should send me if you want me to change jobs).  If the position is one I would like to follow up on I will also communicate via both methods.  Depending on the time of day/my availability I will email back after reading the description that I would like to talk further about the position.  When I have more time to talk and ask questions about the position I will call to follow up.

If I know it will be several hours to the next day before I can call them I always email.  If I decide I am going to call them back at the next break I have I will forego the email and just call.  Of course if I get their VM I will leave a message and send the email.

As far as an unwritten rule, I will normally go with one contact method over the other depending on how `fast I want to get a response` (read desperately unemployed I am).  If they have called and emailed I feel they have said either method is now fine.  I may send an email back and then follow up with a phone call, but eventually if I want to pursue the position I will need to talk to the recruiter in person or over the phone.

Answer (score 0):

What unwritten rule? You emailed them back, and that should be good enough. Email them again tomorrow morning "Just following up" and follow with a phone call gain the morning after tomorrow morning - if you haven't heard from them, that is. Recruiters usually move pretty fast, especially those recruiters that work on commission.